# Сшивка двух изображений

Tags: python, c++, opencv

Есть два изображения с двух камер и их необходимо сшить. С opencv, не получается. Делал систему кругового обзора на длинную грузовую машину и из-за того что она длинная, 4 камер не хватает. Поэтому я поставил 6 камер. С боковых сторон по две камеры и изображение с этих двух камер надо сшить. Убираю рыбий (фишай) глаз с камер, делаю 3 вид сверху и остается сшить.

Как еще можно сшить два изображения без opencv?

Сшивание делаю по этому коду: [https://github.com/WillBrennan/ImageStitching](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6S2d.jpg)

Картинки с разрешением:

```
w = 1200
h = 500
```

1 изображение:
[image: 1 изображение]

2 изображение:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Результат 1:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Результат 2: (Так получается когда я не убираю рыбий глаз и камера больше видит)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Эээ? Взять фотошоп? Или таки поясните что же понимаете под этой фразой…

Comment: Что за фотографии? Панорамы / спутниковые снимки / ... ? Проблема в подборе относительного смещения перед сшивкой или в коррекции яркости / цветности ?

Comment: @Alexey Ten дописал

Comment: @Chorkov дописал

Comment: Вы хотите программно сшить? А почему `opencv` использовать не хотите? В каком формате изображения, которые вы хотите сшить? Если формат довольно простой, то нет ничего сложного запрограммировать это сшивание, просто сесть и разобраться, как устроен формат и как нужно объединить данные в более большую картинку.

Comment: @CrazyElf да хочу программно сшить. у opencv не получается сшить(обычные картинки из интернета сьшет без проблем, а мои нет). изображения формата jpg

Comment: Ну так может надо разбираться с тем, почему `opencv` не справляется - написать в вопросе какие ошибки и проблемы выходят?

Comment: @CrazyElf ошибок нету. я передаю два изображения, но он мне возвращает 1 изображение иногда 2 изображение

Comment: @CrazyElf добавил картинки и немного текста

Comment: @CrazyElf еще немного отредактировал и поменял картинки, не те сюда загрузил был оказывается

Comment: Попробуем переоткрыть. Осталось только дописать словами - что именно не так с результатами, почему они вас не устраивают. Даже если вам это очевидно из самой картинки, лучше всё-равно добавить описание словами.

Comment: Результат 2 вроде норм. Только вывернуть немного

Comment: @eri 2 результат это 1 изображение. Так получается когда я не убираю рыбий глаз и камера больше видит.

Comment: В вопрос, всё это добавляйте в вопрос. Комментарии не все будут читать. И вообще их скорее всего потом модераторы почистят.